# What is a good practice to access the parent component's ref inside its child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm coding a small library with a simple structure: one parent component can contain multiple components of the same type as direct children. Here is a sample schematic diagram for the app:

[image: The example of an app's structure]

By current design, a `ChildComponent` must address a variety of properties of their parent `MainComponent`, and I am looking for a good practice that can help achieve that or an alternative of an app structure that will lead to a good practice.

My considerations:

- **Using [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)**. This won't go well with the goal in mind because of the nature of contexts. As per linked documentation:

  > Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components, such as the current authenticated user, theme, or preferred language.
- **Passing all required props from `MainComponent` to `ChildComponent`**. Despite I meet this approach quite often, I don't think it is good because it leads to duplicate code.

Comment: I don't see how passing a DOM reference is any different from other reference variables.

Comment: If you are passing ref to a function component you will need to use forwardRef: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is with **Props**, as you already mentioned. If you are passing only one level down it is probably the best option:
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

If you need to pass code to several children and grandchildren, using props will get annoying, that is called  "propdrilling". You can avoid it using a **Context** that will provide to all the components that want to consume it:
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Another alternative for larger applications is **Redux**. Is has a store and enables your components to interact with the Redux store. The downside is that it requires a lot of boilerplate.
https://react-redux.js.org/